# $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and Lipschitz continuous, then $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, lipschitz-functions

> $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and Lipschitz continuous, then $f\in
>  L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Denote the Lipschitz constant of $f$ as $C$, suppose $f$ is not bounded a.e., then
$\mu(\{f> k+C)\}) > 0 $ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Take $x_k\in \{f> k+C)\}$, we have 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |f| dx \geq \int_{B(x_k,1)} |f| dx \geq \int_{B(x_k,1)} k\;dx = k\alpha(N)$$
where $\alpha(N)$ is the volume of the unit ball.

The last inequality is from the following, since $f(x_k) \geq k+C$, then for each $y\in B(x_k,1)$, we have 
$$|f(x_k) - f(y)|\leq C |x_k - y| \leq C, $$
therefore $|f| \geq k$ on $B(x_k, 1)$.

This gives us a contradiction since $k\alpha(N)$ is not bounded.

Is this proof correct?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see where you're using the Lipschitz condition, or how you conclude that $|f|\geqslant k$ on $B(x_k,1)$.

Comment: I would be explicit in explaining why the Lipschitz condition implies the final inequality, but yes, the proof looks correct.

Comment: Since $f(x_k) > k+C$, and $$|f(x_k) - f(y)| \leq C$$ for all $y\in B(x_k,1)$, therefore $|f| \geq k $ on the ball $B(x_k,1)$.

Comment: Right, I would just include that line in the proof.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys very much!